# How to prevent ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock from dismissing modal?

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, alassetslibrary, alasset

The first time an app is run on the iPad when accessing ALAssetsLibrary you get the standard alert "'Appname' Would Like to Use Your Current Location. This allows access to location information in photos and videos." However, this alert is automatically dismissing my modal view controller.

Is there a way to prevent my modal view controller from being dismissed? It is not desirable behavior for my app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the alert triggers AppDelegate willResignActivate, which I was using to perform a logout action in my app.